# Cannot go inside a directory in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Following lines are copy pasted from my terminal:

```
 anmol@anmol-K53E:~/Downloads$ ls
    google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb
    libqtwebkit4_2.3.2-0ubuntu6_i386.deb
    LinuxLive USB Creator 2.8.30.exe
    skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
    sublime-text_build-3065_amd64.deb
    tomorrow-theme-master
    VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle
    Web Development.mm
    zipped color

 anmol@anmol-K53E:~/Downloads$ /tomorrow-theme-master
    bash: /tomorrow-theme-master: No such file or directory

 anmol@anmol-K53E:~/Downloads$
```

Why can't I access the **`tomorrow-theme-master`** folder?

Comment: O/S shell has a command to CHANGE DIRECTORY **`cd`** `/tomorrow-theme-master` (shall work, if there is such root-level sub-directory present ). Your copy/paste syntax asked O/S to find and execute a file, named `tomorrow-theme-master`, located in the system root `/` node ( which was reported to fail )

Comment: What does `ls -l`say?

Comment: anmol@anmol-K53E:~/Downloads$ cd /tomorrow-theme-master
bash: cd: /tomorrow-theme-master: No such file or directory

Comment: Actually what I want to do is change the theme of Vim editor, for that I need to move a file from tomorrow-theme-master into the vim/colors directory. However, as the I cant access the tomorrow-theme-master folder from the terminal, I cant move forward

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the path is incorrect.  The terminal is attempting to find a folder at the root level directory, which doesn't exist - it's only in your Downloads folder.

You're currently in that folder anyway, so you should be able to change to it  (omit the leading slash):

```
cd tomorrow-theme-master/
```

Comment: Stackoverflow wont allow me to do that, says I need 15 reputation!